# use grep to count the number of times a word got repeated in a file

Tags: bash, shell, grep

For instance, I have a file "a.xml". Inside this file it is just one line as

```
<queue><item><cause><item>
```

I want to find how many times `<item>` occurs, and in this case it is 2.

However, if I run:

```
grep -c "<item>" a.xml
```

It will only give me 1 because grep stops as soon as it matches the first `<item>`.

So the problem is how to use a simple shell/bash command that returns the number of times `<item>` occurs?

Comment: not really. Gnu grep has been ported to Win32

Comment: @kurumi I tried "Git Bash" and "Command Prompt" under Win7, but grep -o does not work. Is it that I should update/install grep for windows?

Comment: its here gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm‎

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try something like:

```
grep -o "<item>" a.xml | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk you can do that in a single command:

```
awk -F '<item>' '{print NF-1}' a.xml
```

#### Online Demo: http://ideone.com/vheDgq

OR to get total count for whole file use:

```
awk -F '<item>' '{s+=NF-1}END{print s}' a.xml
```

Comment: I have tested it before posting. Can you please tell me for which input it doesn't work?

Comment: Note: For multi-line files this prints the number of items on each line, rather than a total count for the whole file.

Comment: Yes that is true and if requirement is to get total that is easy to do in awk but I wasn't sure about multiline aggregate from the question.

Comment: Why is it NF-1? (sry that I am not familiar with awk) @anubhava

Comment: `NF-1` to get the count of token delimited by `<item>`. If there is one `<item>` in string there will be 2 tokens and correct count of delimiter is `NF-1`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking to count '< item>' alone, then I like MillaresRoo's `grep -o` solution.  If you are looking to count items more generally, then consider:

```
$ sed 's/></>\n</g' a.xml | sort | uniq -c
      1 <cause>
      2 <item>
      1 <queue>
```

Or, showing the input explicitly on the command line:

```
$ echo '<queue><item><cause><item>' | sed 's/></>\n</g' | sort | uniq -c
      1 <cause>
      2 <item>
      1 <queue>
```